# Nautilus doesn't mount in Xmonad: Not authorized to perform operation

Tags: gnome, 13.10, mount, nautilus, xmonad

I'm using Xmonad as my window manager.

In the application nautilus, whenever I try to mount my usb sticks, it shows me the dialog `"Not authorized to perform operation."`

I have tried putting this in `~/.xsession` file:

`nautilus --no-desktop -n &`

But that doesn't work.

This is my current `~/.xsession` file:

```
#!/bin/bash

gnome-settings-daemon &
exec dbus-launch --exit-with-session xmonad
```

Also, when I start a pure gnome session, everything works fine. Any idea on how to make nautilus ask password or mount the usb stick on clicking it in the nautilus ?

Comment: Have you tried launching nautilus as root from a terminal?

Comment: @bleeves yes. But I want to use nautilus as a normal user. Security wise, opening nautilus is a bad practice.

Comment: ^ Opening nautilus as a root user is a bad practice.

Comment: Agreed. I was asking if he had tried sudo to ascertain the reason it was locked, not recommending an answer.

Comment: There must be a permission to be granted somewhere... I would not accept solutions that require root access or modifying fstab. It is most likely with polkit setup and again, I wouldn't like to modify the polkit rules.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Disks from Dash

   [image]
2. Choose the desired disk/partition

   [image]
3. Edit Mount Options

   [image]
4. Uncheck require additional authorization

   [image]

Comment: This didn't work for exFAT.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start polkit in your xsession.

You most likely have a `.desktop` file in `/etc/xdg/autostart` in the path somewhere with the full path to your polkit daemon.

For me adding `/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1` in `~/.Xsession` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will have this error if using XRDP. You need to login directly to Xwindow 
from KVM.

Answer (score 0):

This nice [overview of polkit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit) from archlinux wiki is very useful to understand the topic.

In my case, since I'm running a custom configured desktop composed of awesome, nodm, consolekit, and other hand picked software, I have to start a polkit authentication agent manually. This is provided by mate-polkit-bin package in debian. I believe xmonad will be a very similar case.

Before: thunar failing to mount, saying "Failed to mount XXX. Not authorized to perform operation."

After running mate-polkit: thunar upon attempt to mount asks me to authenticate according to the polkit rules for the given action. This is actually requested by the udisks tool that thunar uses to do the mounting. Once correctly authenticated, devices mount as expected.

Solution is to add a polkit authentication agent (like mate-polkit) to your session startup commands (autostart).

Comment: Do you know what polkit agent needs to be run on Unity or a gnome session in Ubuntu ?

Comment: I'm not sure, try examine `apt-cache search polkit`. I've seen somewhere, but cannot remember, that gnome session possibly has the agent built in. The mate package might work for you. See `man pkcheck` and try testing some admin action with the --allow-user-interaction parameter to see if you have things wired up.